# ngTemplateOutletContext with ng-tempate and for loop for the reference value with angular error variable doesn't exits

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-template

I have an Array of a component as below

```
 <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="controlArrayContainer"
     [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{controls:control?.componentProperty?.formArray, index: i}">
 </ng-container>
```

Passing the data from the context as

```
{controls:control?.componentProperty?.formArray, index: i}
```

In the template section consuming the data as below

```
<ng-template #controlArrayContainer let-control="controls" let-index="index">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let layout of controls; let i = index">
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Keep getting an exception during the compile time as

```
Error: projects/falcon-core/src/lib/component/reactive-controls/reactive-controls.component.html:32:41 - error TS2339: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'ReactiveControlsComponent'.

32     <ng-container *ngFor="let layout of controls; let i = index">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are using `let-control`, so you should use `control` in the `ngFor` loop, instead of `controls`:

```
<ng-template #controlArrayContainer let-control="controls" let-index="index">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let layout of control; let i = index">
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```